# Angular-mocks Uncaught TypeError, reason for this error

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js

I'm setting up a standard (but simpler) test environment for an Angular app. What I'm using is Mocha, Chai, Angular, Angular-Mocks (since that's needed unless you use Jasmine afaik).

Angular and angular-mocks are version 1.3.10, but this happens for 1.3.15 as well, these are the two versions I tested with.

The problem is that I receive this error from the js console when loading the angular-mocks script.

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The lines it's complaining about in angular-mocks is:

```
(window.beforeEach || window.setup)(function() {
  currentSpec = this;
});
```

So angular-mocks is trying to grab a global function which doesn't exist in this case, right? Why, and how do I prevent it? Is there a actual  problem?

[Here's a js fiddle with the code and the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/miphe/7c5sxb6w/)

I then get the following error when trying to use inject()

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: inject is not defined
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: How do you run your unit tests?

Comment: did you find the root of this cause? I am also having this issue

Comment: @SumanLama I haven't removed the TypeError, but that issue is pretty harmless. It is not what is causing the uncaught reference error when using inject().

Comment: @JBNizet I'm running the tests in the browser as shown in the js fiddle.

Comment: @miphe hmm, so what was the issue? How did you solve it?

Comment: @SumanLama I haven't solved the Fiddle, and I need to dig more into the TypeError to have a good explanation for it, but for the latter at least we know it's harmless.

Comment: @miphe I meant about `Uncaught ReferenceError: inject is not defined` issue